# Copy file from local to remote SSH with spaces in username

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, ssh, scp

I have to copy a file from my local machine to a remote server. The problem is, from what I'm understanding, is the space in my username ("User Name").

I've tried the following in command prompt:

```
scp -rv C:\Users\User Name\Downloads\filename.c username@path.edu:/home/student/username
```

But it's telling me:

```
C:/Users/User: No such file or directory
Name/Downloads/filename.c: No such filSink: \001scp: C:/Users/User: No such file or directory
e or diSink: \001scp: Name/Downloads/filepath.c: No such file or directory
rectory
...
debug1: Exit status 1
```

I've also tried removing my initial "C:" and "C:\Users\User Name" and removing the space in "User Name" from the command but it still doesn't copy and gives the same response.

Is there any other way I could copy or am I doing something wrong myself with that prompt?

Comment: Try `scp -rv "C:\Users\User Name\Downloads\filename.c" username@path.edu:/home/student/username`

Comment: @Bodo it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes around file names that contain spaces

```
scp -rv "C:\Users\User Name\Downloads\filename.c" username@path.edu:/home/student/username
```